# HQL for this entity model?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

Given the following entity one-to-many model:

One Repository can be linked to many AuditRecords.

Many Audit records can all link to the same AuditRecord

[image]

What would be the HQL query to get the *latest* (by accessTime) Audit record for each distinct Repository?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it once and I don't have access to that code now. This will give you latest `AuditRecords` and then you can access `Repository` from it. I create this with what I remember so...

```
select ar from AuditRecord ar
where ar.accessTime = (select max(ari.accessTime) from AuditRecord ari where ari.repositoryId = ar.repositoryId)
```